# Vuejs + Github Pages not working properly when deployed

Tags: javascript, github, vue.js

I am trying to deploy a VueJs application to Github Pages and I am following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@codetheorist/vue-up-your-github-pages-the-right-way-955486220418, however I am getting the following errors:

1. My images are not being correctly loaded, for example there is a requisition trying to access an image with the URL https://myGitHubUser.github.io/my-project-namestatic/img/img.png

Also, I have image subfolders that weren't loaded to the dist folder. In the HTML I am using the path like '../../assets/images/myImage.png' to access them.

2. My router-view is not being loaded. My other components that does not rely on router-view are working perfectly.

I tried a lot of alternatives but none of them worked as expected.

Comment: Did you solved?